# JQ delete entries based on condtition

Tags: json, jq

My json looks like the following

```
{
  
  "a6acc79a-1776-1719-a400-e78e2cda4dd1": [
    {
      "previous": {
        "id": "cf091d81-d0cb-3b31-ae15-451c551cf2fb",
        "startDateTime": 1,
        "endDateTime":2
      },
      "current": {
        "id": "2c05d2ad-ba36-3f61-9c12-5d2294aa4e3a",
        "startDateTime": 1,
        "endDateTime": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "previous": {
        "id": "f255daf7-b8fc-3b73-99bf-ec7d26b37748",
        "startDateTime": 3,
        "endDateTime": 3
      },
      "current": {
        "id": "9e0f131c-3043-3262-8d26-9c8b3bd0f516",
        "startDateTime":3,
        "endDateTime": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete entries that don't match this condition `startDateTime >= 3` and the expected output is

```
{
  
    "a6acc79a-1776-1719-a400-e78e2cda4dd1": [
      {
        "previous": {
          "id": "f255daf7-b8fc-3b73-99bf-ec7d26b37748",
          "startDateTime": 3,
          "endDateTime": 3
        },
        "current": {
          "id": "9e0f131c-3043-3262-8d26-9c8b3bd0f516",
          "startDateTime":3,
          "endDateTime": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any help is appreciated. I was able to delete some entries but not full objects.
My attempt so far is
jq -r 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(if ((.key | endswith("DateTime")) and (.value | tonumber >= 3))  then empty  end) end) '

Comment: Please clarify the requirements to make it clear which objects exactly you want deleted.  E.g. if previous.startDateTime is 2 and .current.startDateTime is 3 within the same JSON object.

Comment: @peak previous.startDateTime greater than 2 or .current.startDateTime greater than 2

Comment: I am confused because you say "I want to delete entries that match this condition startDateTime >= 3", but your expected output shows *only* items that match that condition. Did you mean `<`?

Comment: @larsks I want to delete every entries that  don't match this condition startDateTime >= 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following produces the desired result, and is hopefully clear enough to help you formulate the precise solution to your problem:

```
map_values(
  map(
    if has("previous")
    then select( .previous.startDateTime >= 3 and .current.startDateTime >= 3)
    else .
    end
  )
)
```

Comment: Add a condition to filter out empty arrays after applying the filter 
`jq 'map_values(map(if has("previous") then select( .previous.startDateTime >= 1628640234000 or .current.startDateTime >= 1628640234000) else . end ))  | with_entries(select((.value | length) > 0))'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an illustrative program that produces the desired result using `walk`:

```
walk (if type == "array"
      then map(select(
         if type == "object" and (.previous and .previous.startDateTime<3 or .current.startDateTime<3)
         then empty
     else . end) )
      else .
      end)
```